# make 'unpack' is up to date; executables will not run

Tags: c, makefile

I have a make file which can compile and immediatly execute 3 c programs.
The `make all` command works great but `make unpack` and `make remove` result in

> make: 'unpack' is up to date

(and same thing with `make remove`).

Note (summary from comment):
It is OK to always compile (even if not necessary for being up to date) and execute. My problem is that it does not always execute the program.

Below is my code:

```
all: assign4.c
    gcc assign4.c
    ./a.out output.tar test1.txt test2.txt testDir
    @echo "\n\n~~~~~output.tar created~~~~~\n-Use 'make remove' to remove test files\n-Use 'make unpack' to restore test files from output.tar\n\n"

unpack: unpack.c
    gcc unpack.c -o unpack
    ./unpack

remove: removeTestFiles.c
    gcc removeTestFiles.c -o remove
    ./remove
```

I also tried using `.PHONY` like this:

```
all: assign4.c
    gcc assign4.c
    ./a.out output.tar test1.txt test2.txt testDir
    @echo "\n\n~~~~~output.tar created~~~~~\n-Use 'make remove' to remove test files\n-Use 'make unpack' to restore test files from output.tar\n\n"


#.PHONY: unpack
unpack: unpack.c
    gcc unpack.c -o unpack
    .PHONY : ./unpack

.PHONY: remove
remove: removeTestFiles.c
    gcc removeTestFiles.c -o remove
    ./remove
```

but for some reason, I get an error when I run `make unpack` that says `make: .PHONY: Command not found` which doesn't make any sense because I commented out that .phony, but left the phony in remove and `make remove` works perfectly...

Comment: For "unpack", do you want to always first compile before executing? If yes, why? If no, why do you put both in one rule? Also what keeps you from making one rule for compiling unpack if neccessary and another rule for using it?

Comment: Are you familiar with phony targets, which get executed independenlty from freshness of input files? https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html

Comment: I don't need to compile unpack every time but when I hand in my assignment, I want my prof to just be able to run `make`, `make remove` and then `make unpack` to simply compile and run everything required for the first time

Comment: @Yunnosch According to that document you can add `.PHONY : ` before the command? And that makes it compile regardless of if changes were made or not (which is what I want)? But i got the error `.PHONY: command not found`

Comment: What make are you using?

Comment: @Yunnosch 4.1 currently

Comment: Would that be GNU make?

Comment: @Yunnosch yes sir it is

Comment: I tested successfully....

Comment: Please show (by editing your question, adding a "I also tried: ...") the make file using `.PHONY`.

Comment: @Yunnosch just updated

Comment: @Yunnosch woops I had .phony in the wrong place, I found my mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will execute unpack always, even if it is normally considered up to date:

```
.PHONY: unpack 

unpack:
    gcc unpack.c -o unpack
    ./unpack
```

Note on your "I also tried" version, I cannot reproduce the error message you show. But your makefile has an unwanted `#` and a specific phony target is used like `make unpack`.

If you also want "unpack.c" to be compiled if otherwise necessary or be not compiled if not necessary, then you need to make more rules.

This is for GNU make according to
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html

I tested with GNU Make 3.81

Note on testing:
I tried this with an "echo" in front of each command (double checking the tabs where needed).
The output for `make unpack` is

```
echo gcc unpack.c -o unpack
gcc unpack.c -o unpack
echo ./unpack
./unpack
```